# How can I get to the stream of the composite MinibatchSource?

Tags: cntk

If I create a MinibatchSource like this:

```
reader_test = MinibatchSource(ImageDeserializer('test_map.txt', StreamDefs(
    features = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), # first column in map file is referred to as 'image'
    labels   = StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes)      # and second as 'label'
)))
```

then I can get to the features stream like this:

```
reader_test.streams.features
```

But, if I create the MiniBatchSource like this:

```
image_source = ImageDeserializer('test_map.txt', StreamDefs(
    features = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), # first column in map file is referred to as 'image'
    labels   = StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes)      # and second as 'label'
))

text_source = CTFDeserializer("test_map2.txt")
text_source.map_input('index', dim=1, format="dense")
text_source.map_input('piece_type', dim=6, format="dense")

# define a composite reader
reader_config = ReaderConfig([image_source, text_source])
mb_source = reader_config.minibatch_source()
```

Trying this:

```
mb_source.streams.features
```

results in:

```
AttributeError: 'MinibatchSource' object has no attribute 'streams'
```

How can I get to the features stream?

Comment: That's a bug that will be solved in the upcoming beta.

Answer (score -1):

This has been fixed since a long time ago.